# Series reversion of polynomial using Bürmann-Lagrange series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, lagrange-inversion

I saw this formula which inverts a series

https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/B%C3%BCrmann-Lagrange_series

It's straightforward about a=0, for roots close to zero, or for non-composite functions. Its harder for larger solutions. I am trying to compute one of the large roots of the polynomial and then square this result as a single series.

$$
F(w)= f(a) + \sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(w-b)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}[f'(z)\left[\left( \frac{z-a}{g(z) - b} \right)^n \right]]_{z = a}
$$

Consider the polynomial $$g(z)=-(z^3+3z^2-5z)=.15=w$$ which is equal to $-z(z-r_1)(z-r_2)$ for the two roots of the ancillary quadratic. Hence we have:

$$r_1=a,g(r_1)=0=b$$

So I am trying to find a series for the square of one of the roots, which for the large ones is around $17.63$. This means $$f(a)=z^2$$

It works for $f(a)=z$ but not squared

Here is  $$  \frac{.15^n}{n!} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} \frac{2x}{(x(x-r_2))^n}$$

about $x=-r_1$

Taking the first three terms shows it gets close but does not work

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4.192582403%5E2-2%28.15%5E1%29%2F%28+%28a+%2B+b%29%5E1%29%2B.15%5E2*%28+%283+a+%2B+b%29+%29%2F%28a%5E2+%28a+%2B+b%29%5E3%29%2Cb%3D-4.192582403%2Ca%3D-1.192582403

The first two terms get very close, 17.6335 vs 17.633343, but fails on the third.

What mistake is made?

Edit I seem to have made an error regarding substitutions in wolfram. Updated, gives   17.63334294:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4.192582403%5E2-2%28.15%5E1%29%2F%28+%28a+%2B+b%29%5E1%29-1*.15%5E2*%28+%283+a+%2B+b%29+%29%2F%28a%5E2+%28a+%2B+b%29%5E3%29%2Ca%3D-4.192582403%2Cb%3D-1.192582403

which is much closer  to the correct value. Dealing with sign changes and substitutions is tricky.

Comment: [This series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-4%29%5E2%2Bsum%5B%28x-4%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B2w+%28%28w%2B4%29%2F%28w%5E3%2B3w%5E2-5w-4%29%29%5En%2C%7Bw%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C5%7D%5D%2Cw%3D-4%2Cx%3D-0.15) gives $17.633\dots$ alternatively